# How to make complex data cleaning in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a DataFrame as following.

```
lineNum        id         name            Cname           score
  1            001        Jack             Math           99
  2            002        Jack             English        110
  3            003        Jack             Chinese        90
  4            003        Jack             Chinese        90
  5            004        Tom              Math           Nan
  6            005        Tom              English        75
  7            006        Tom              Chinese        85
```

As you see, I want to data cleaning for this data.
1) delete the duplicate value which is line 3 and line 4.
2) deal with ths unreasonable value. In line 2, Jack's English get 110 which is over the max value 100. I want to set his score to the mean value for all students' english score.
3) deal with the Nan value.  Tom's Math score is Nan. I want to change to the mean value for all students' math score.

I can do every requirement respectively. But I don't know how to do all these three requirements. Thanks!

Comment: why don't you do each requirement 1 after the other, like first get rid of duplicates, then for all null and out-of-bound values, replace with mean

Comment: you can use `Dataframe.drop_duplicate()`, then to get rid of the 110 score is easy as you know the max is 100, and then use `Dataframe.fillna()` for the nan values

Answer (score 2):

***plan***

- I drop duplicates to start.
- use `mask` to make scores > than 100 null
- filter new dataframe and group by with mean
- map means and use it to fill nulls

---

```
d = df.drop_duplicates(['id', 'name', 'Cname'])

s0 = d.score
s1 = s0.mask(s > 100)
m = s1.mask(s1 > 100).notnull()

d.assign(score=s1.fillna(d.Cname.map(d[m].groupby('Cname').score.mean())))

   lineNum  id  name    Cname  score
0        1   1  Jack     Math   99.0
1        2   2  Jack  English  110.0
2        3   3  Jack  Chinese   90.0
4        5   4   Tom     Math   99.0
5        6   5   Tom  English   75.0
6        7   6   Tom  Chinese   85.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
cols = ['id','name','Cname','score']
#remove duplicates by columns
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=cols)
#replace values > 100 to NaN
df.loc[df['score'] > 100, 'score'] = np.nan
#replace NaN by mean for all students by subject
df['score'] = df.groupby('Cname')['score'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
print (df)
   lineNum  id  name    Cname  score
0        1   1  Jack     Math   99.0
1        2   2  Jack  English   75.0
2        3   3  Jack  Chinese   90.0
4        5   4   Tom     Math   99.0
5        6   5   Tom  English   75.0
6        7   6   Tom  Chinese   85.0
```

Alternative solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for `NaN`:

```
cols = ['id','name','Cname','score']
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=cols)
df['score'] = df['score'].mask(df['score'] > 100)

df['score'] = df.groupby('Cname')['score'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
print (df)
   lineNum  id  name    Cname  score
0        1   1  Jack     Math   99.0
1        2   2  Jack  English   75.0
2        3   3  Jack  Chinese   90.0
4        5   4   Tom     Math   99.0
5        6   5   Tom  English   75.0
6        7   6   Tom  Chinese   85.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider `.apply(func)' if the data is not too big.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('sample.txt', delimiter='\s+', na_values='Nan')  # Your sample data
df = df.set_index('lineNum').drop_duplicates()

def deal_with(x):
    if (x['score'] > 100.) or (pd.isnull(x['score'])):
        df_ = df[df['id'] != x['id']]
        x['score'] = df_.loc[df_['Cname'] == x['Cname'], 'score'].mean()

    return x

print(df.apply(deal_with, axis=1))

         id  name    Cname  score
lineNum                          
1         1  Jack     Math   99.0
2         2  Jack  English   75.0
3         3  Jack  Chinese   90.0
5         4   Tom     Math   99.0
6         5   Tom  English   75.0
7         6   Tom  Chinese   85.0
```